# BERT & Multiprocessing

Tags: python, docker, concurrency, multiprocessing, multicore

I have been trying to multiprocess BERT embedding generation.

Have tried to code as below but fails to take off.

```py
bert_command = 'bert-serving-start -model_dir uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12 -num_worker 40'
process = subprocess.Popen(bert_command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
from bert_serving.client import BertClient
```

then using

```py
import concurrent.futures
```

to multiprocess the embedding generation

```py
def embedding_dic(file_list):
    dic={}
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        for file, e in zip(file_list, executor.map(embedding_file, file_list)):
            dic[file]=e
    return dic

def embedding_file(file):
    file_obj = open(form_path+file, 'r')
    file_read = file_obj.readlines()
    file_obj.close()
    file_read = [i.rstrip() for i in file_read if not(bool(not i or i.isspace()))] 
    file_read =[' |||'.join(file_read )]
    bc = BertClient(check_length=False)
    try:
        embedding = bc.encode(file_read)
    except ValueError: 
        embedding=None
    return embedding
```

But the flow gets stuck at

```py
embedding = bc.encode(file_read)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regarding the Machine Configuration:

**System information**

- Debian
- TensorFlow version: 1.13
- Python version: 3.6
- `bert-as-service` version: 1.8.9
- CPU model and memory: 48 cores Docker Machine & 60 GB Memory

Comment: what does "get stuck at" mean? Is there an error message, or does it just hang indefinitely?

Comment: at a guess your bert serving process is stuck trying to write output to stdout, if you're capturing it (i.e. via `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`) then you need to do something with it

Comment: generally you're better off using shell scripts to get the system into the right state (i.e. running `bert-serving-start`) and having your Python code just assume this is OK.  it's much easier to debug code when it's not spinning up large programs in the background, also while developing you can also do this manually and get finer control over things

Comment: @olooney yes stucks indefinetly !

Comment: @sammason as suggested I did run Bert-Server through console. 

```bash
bert-serving-start -model_dir /home/jovyan/work/BERT/uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12 -num_worker 4
```

Here is the output

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC3VV.png

Comment: added as a reference:
https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service/issues/480
https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service/issues/300